# Why it is a bad practice to create an object within a function in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I am newbie in C++. The interviewer said it's bad practice to create an object within a function. Is it so?

```
#include <iostream.h>

class linkedlist {
    int value;
    linkedlist *next;
    static linkedlist *p=NULL;

    void insert(int data) {
        linkedlist node;
        node.value=data;
        node.next=NULL;

        if(p==NULL)
            p=node;
        else {
            p->next=node;
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    linkedlist h;
    h.insert(10);
    h.insert(20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The whole code is all but good practice. Starting at `#include<iostream.h>`.

Comment: @LogicStuff I cant understand your comment..

Comment: @LogicStuff What is there to downvote? You could have waited. I clearly said I am a newbie

Comment: Look at std::make_pair as an example.  If the standard library does it how can it be bad practice?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: ok. I will look at it. std::make_pair is new to me. I have a doubt. If we create an object within a function, then the function stack has reference to the newly created object in heap right?

Comment: Question not properly formatted. To the topic: we don't implement our own non-generic linked lists in C++, there's `std::list`/`std::forward_list` for that. `linklist` in reality represents just a node, and that `static` data member smells. You must be getting a compiler error about assigning a non-pointer type to a pointer type... You'd get a dangling pointer anyway.

Comment: @user7937993  But in your code you aren't putting it on the heap - you are making an object on the local stack.  And then you stick it in the list but when the function ends it is garbage.  You need to allocate the object on the heap.

Comment: Why are you implementing _node_ and _linked list_ functionality together in the same class?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad I understand that. I can create a separate class for structure of node. I just wrote that code at that moment.

Comment: Off topic: Strongly recommend separating the linked list from the nodes. Make a `LinkedList` class that manages a list of instances of a `Node` class. You will probably find this easier to work with and more extensible. Currently you can have one and only one list, because `p` is `static`, and that is not very useful.

Comment: @user7937993 But C++ also has return value optimization. If you return the stack object it will be moved rather than copied and you do not loose anything when you go out of scope. You just need to be careful and write a move constructor if you allocate heap memory within the class.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I understand. Thanks

Comment: Your code does not compile so it is hard to know what *exactly* your question is.

Comment: @Galik There was lots of discussion before you came here. I did not ask for the execution of the program. Read the question and others comments clearly.

Comment: @user7937993 The comments are not part of the question. You should either present code that does not compile and ask why it does not compile or else provide code that does compile and ask if it is good practice or not. But code that does not compile is never "good practice" so it doesn't really tell us what practice you are asking about. We can hazard a guess, but... it is better to have a clear question.

Comment: For example your question is basically *"is it a bad practice to create an object within a function in C++?"*. Th answer is that depends on how the object is created and how it is returned. There are ways to do it that are bad and ways to do it that are good. Your example doesn't tell us which ones you are talking about because it uses elements of two (which is why it doesn't compile).

Comment: @Galik I told I am a newbie to C++ and how do you expect me to tell the good and bad way? By the way, If I know the good and bad methods, why would I ask first of all ? Everyone except you, understand what I mean. The facts such as:

a) newbie to C++

b) I had an interview

c) is this a good practice of instantiating objects

clearly focus on "object instantiation" not on program execution

Comment: @user7937993 Like I said, if you do not know how to make the code compile, then ask why it doesn't compile. We can help you with that. But if you want to know if a specific technique is "good practice" then you have to provide us an example of that technique. It has to be **legal** C++. The only answer I can give you for code that does not compile is that it is **never** "good practice" to write code that does not compile.

Comment: And the fact the experts can guess what you probably mean doesn't really help other newbies like yourself to benefit from the question.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is "lifetime"; the node you created lives only in the stack frame of the function and when the function terminates its memory is reclaimed. The static pointer `p` however will still link it and this will lead to "undefined behavior" when someone later accesses the linked list.

Using local objects is not bad in general, it's only bad if you expect them to survive the end of the function, because they don't.

You should allocate long-living objects the object on the free store, by using `new`.

Comment: Thanks. Then my insert changes to the below structure right?

void insert(){
linkedlist *node = new linkedlist;
node->value=data;
node->next=NULL;
if(p==NULL) p=node;
else {
p->next=node;
p=p->next;
}
}

Comment: @user7937993 Yes, that gets you started, but note that you can only make a list 2 nodes deep with that code. You will need a loop to find the end of the list before adding if you want to create a list of arbitrary length.

Comment: @user7937993: that code would work for a node, but not for more than one node (hint: you are overwriting `p->next` with the new node address... who tells you that `p->next` was NULL?). The easy way to handle simply-linked lists node insertion is to place new nodes at the beginning of the list and the code requires no `if` at all.

Comment: @6502 you mean to say that there is no head pointer to track the beginning and end of linkedlist right?

Comment: @user7937993: to append to the end of a linked list you either need to keep a pointer to the last element or you need to follow all the links for each insertion. Inserting elements at the beginning instead is simpler and requires no `if` statements: `Node *n = new Node; n.next = p; p = n;`.